# How to install OpenLayers using NPM

Tags: npm, webpack, openlayers

There seem to be two OpenLayers packages available over NPM:

**Option 1**

```
npm install ol
```

which then can be used:

```js
import OlMap from 'ol/map';
import OlView from 'ol/view';
import OlTile from 'ol/layer/tile';
import OlLayerVector from 'ol/layer/vector';
import OlSourceVector from 'ol/source/vector';
```

**Option 2**

```
npm install openlayers
```

```js
import * as ol from 'openlayers';
```

Why two packages?
What is the correct way, if any?

The second one looks more elegant to me, but OL's documentation actually mentions the first one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/openlayers

Comment: It's about the bundle side. if you import all, must be the file size bigger.

Comment: Thank you. What about the npm install command (why two packages)?

Comment: I'm not sure about `openlayers` package, as their install guide, use `ol`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openlayers) explains the difference.
Do not start a project with `openlayers`, it uses closure, which you most likely will not. `ol` is packaged as'state of art' ES2015 modules. It enables your compiler (eg webpack) to only package things you actually use.

> For use with webpack, Rollup, Browserify, or other module bundlers, install the ol package:
>
> `npm install ol`
>
> For use with Closure Library (rare), install the openlayers package and read the tutorial.
>
> `npm install openlayers`

Comment: In addition, the openlayers package has been deprecated, with a recommendation to use the ol package instead.