# How to integrate OpenLayers and jsts in an Angular Application? (with typing)

Tags: angular, openlayers, typescript-typings, jts

i created an Angular 5 project in which i installed by npm the openlayers module and jsts module. I did the following steps:

1. ng new testProject
2. cd /testProject
3. npm install --save openlayers
4. npm install --save jsts
5. npm install --save _at_types/openlayers
6. npm install --save _at_types/jsts

Here is my app.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as ol from 'openlayers';
import * as jsts from 'jsts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('OPENLAYERS: ', ol);
    console.log('JSTS: ', jsts);
  }
}
```

And this result in undefined jsts variable.

If I import classes individually, like:

```
import Coordinate from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Coordinate';
```

the variable is defined correctly, but typing is not working.

How can I do to import and that the typing works?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the npm package `openlayers`. For ES6 projects, there is a package `ol`.

[To quote myself quoting ol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48284602/304179):

> The [NPM page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48284602/304179) explains the difference. Do not start a project with
>   `openlayers`, it uses closure, which you most likely will not. `ol` is
>   packaged as'state of art' ES2015 modules. It enables your compiler (eg
>   webpack) to only package things you actually use.
>
> > For use with webpack, Rollup, Browserify, or other module bundlers, install the ol package:
> >
> > `npm install ol`
> >
> > For use with Closure Library (rare), install the openlayers package and read the tutorial.
> >
> > `npm install openlayers`

For the typescript support of JSTS: [The DefinitelyTyped definitions are incomplete](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/issues/285) and apparently the "browser version" file's module structure is different than the source structure.

If you really really want to have types, add the browser version to your project (eg by adding jsts as JS file to your index.html). It defines the global jsts variable. Then declare jsts in your code to get types:

```
declare var jsts: jsts;
```

Comment: Thanks i understood the closure. However when i add the jsts.js to index.html i can't define `declare var jsts: jsts;` it throws a compilation error because the compiler Cannot find name 'jsts'. If i use `declare var jsts: any;` it works but i loss the types.

Comment: I think I made a mistake there, defining it as global does have extra steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30227263/304179